# How to delete photos from controller or view with cakephp-upload

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am following the [cakephp-upload](http://josediazgonzalez.com/2015/12/05/uploading-files-and-images/) tutorial and everything works out well. However, there is no documentation on how to delete files [except for this, which doesn't really help me out.](https://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)

I imagine that I have to create a controller function to do so, but that's as far as I have right now.

I plan on having a view with an uploaded profile photo, and a remove button to delete it from the view.

Is there any functional example that you can help me find?

Edit: Everything works!... except setting my `photo` field as null. I already checked the validator for `->allowEmpty('photo', 'create')` and `->allowEmpty('photo', 'update')`. I'm running out of ideas, but I'll just make a new question to keep things in order. Thanks a lot!

```
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $brigada = $this->Brigadas
                    ->findById($id)
                    ->firstOrFail();       
        $file = WWW_ROOT . 'files/Brigadas/photo' . $brigada->photo_dir . '/' . $brigada->photo;
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
        $brigada->dir = null;
        $brigada->photo = null;
        $this->Brigadas->save($brigada);
    }
```

Comment: Your `remove` function would simply `unlink` the file specified in the user entity, then set the photo fields to `null` and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need a plugin to delete a file.
Just check if the file exists otherwise you will see all the errors, and finally delete the file.
As for example the following code (In your controller):

```
if(file_exists(<your_url_img>)) {
  unlink(<your_url_img>);
}
```

Comment: It works-ish! I now can't the `photo` field as null, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use Folder and [File utilities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html#file-api)

```
$file = new File(WWW_ROOT.'/img/'.$user->image);
$file->delete();
```